# Using a global Popen object from a Flask route

Tags: python, flask, subprocess, gunicorn

I have a small Flask app, running with Gunicorn configured with one worker. At the app's initialization, it starts up a `subprocess.Popen` and hangs onto it in a global variable.

```py
import subprocess
def my_init():
   ...
   global MY_SUBPROCESS
   MY_SUBPROCESS = subprocess.Popen(["my_process", "foo", "bar"])
```

I'd like to have a route that reports on whether that global subprocess is still running.

```py
@app.route("/poll-subprocess")
def my_poll():
   # expected None if the subprocess is still running, however it's always returning 0
   return MY_SUBPROCESS.poll()
```

The route can see the global Popen object just fine, however the .poll call always returns `0`, even if the process is still running.

I haven't found anything in the `subprocess` documentation that can explain this. I suppose there is a threading issue playing into this somehow?

---

edit: here is a reproducible example:

```py
from subprocess import Popen

from flask import Flask, jsonify
import gunicorn.app.base

# (copied from example https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/custom.html)
class MyApp(gunicorn.app.base.BaseApplication):
    def __init__(self, app, options=None):
        self.options = options or {}
        self.application = app
        super().__init__()

    def load_config(self):
        config = {key: value for key, value in self.options.items()
                  if key in self.cfg.settings and value is not None}
        for key, value in config.items():
            self.cfg.set(key.lower(), value)

    def load(self):
        return self.application

# Spawn our global subprocess
MY_PROCESS = Popen(["sleep", "999"])

# Create the app
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    """Return some info about our global subprocess"""
    return jsonify({
        "obj": str(MY_PROCESS),
        "pid": MY_PROCESS.pid,
        "poll": MY_PROCESS.poll()
    })

# Preview the same info we'll have exposed on a route
print({
    "obj": str(MY_PROCESS),
    "pid": MY_PROCESS.pid,
    "poll": MY_PROCESS.poll()
})

# Launch the app
MyApp(app).run()
```

Example output running it:

```
$ python ./demo.py
{'obj': '<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7fe2f87ed0f0>', 'pid': 20135, 'poll': None}
[2023-04-20 12:13:51 -0400] [20134] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2023-04-20 12:13:51 -0400] [20134] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (20134)
[2023-04-20 12:13:51 -0400] [20134] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-04-20 12:13:51 -0400] [20138] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20138
```

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/
{"obj":"<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7fe2f87ed0f0>","pid":20135,"poll":0}
```

Note it's reporting the same python object and pid as the main thread did when we started the app, however now poll() looks like the process terminated. According to `ps`, it's still running:

```
$ ps -p 20135 -o '%p %a'
  PID COMMAND
20135 sleep 999
```

Comment: If `.poll()` returned 0, then the process *isn't* running - what makes you think it is?  Could it have created a subprocess of its own, which is still running, but exited itself?

Comment: Can see the running process based on its pid and looking at `ps` output -- I'll update with a runnable example

Comment: Thank you -- the question is much improved.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you take gunicorn out of the picture, this is no longer reproducible with baseline flask alone.

Comment: (...consequently, the original rev of the question _really didn't_ have enough information for the issue to be reproducible; nowhere in it was gunicorn mentioned, and if we just run your code from the basic flask development server, it works fine).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a flask issue; it's a gunicorn issue. Gunicorn forks off workers, which then are responsible for handling requests, as children.

This means that when gunicorn runs `waitpid()`, it's doing so from a *sibling* of the `sleep` process, not from its parent. `waitpid()` only works correctly when run from a parent.

If you need to be able to start and monitor child processes, gunicorn is probably the wrong tool for the job.